# WebFonts не работает в Opera

Tags: css

Установил стиль шрифта Jura из Google Web Fonts. Все браузеры его отображают как надо, даже IE. А Opera не хочет! Отображает следующий шрифт из параметра font-family. Может, кто подскажет, как исправить эту фигню?

Comment: А Вы проверьте на другом компьютер Оперу, так как у меня была такая ситуация, когда гугл хром (одинаковая версия) Но на первом компе показывал местами [], а на другом визде все нормально

Answer (score 1):

да.соглашусь с ответом выше.у меня тоже была такая ситуация.для начала проверьте свой сайт здесь(http://browsershots.org/).если там действительно некорректно отображается.то в в нете полно всякой инфы как заменить ту или иную функцию.(в том чесле и отображение шрифта)выбирайте которая вам больше подходит и вперед)))